# Create a field with Range of number

Tags: custom-field

I have a custom field on Lead (Marks__c) which is a number type field with different values. I need to create a field (Profile__c) which should behave something like SF Report's bucket list i.e this field should display different values (A,B,C) depending upon the Marks__c field. These A, B, C values should have a range of Marks. i.e
   Profile__c
   A (Range of Marks 1-10)
   B (Range of Marks 11-20)
   C (Range of Marks 21-30)

How to create this Profile__c field.

Comment: That looks pretty easy for a formula field, what's blocking you ?

Comment: Thanks its done with a formula type field. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I was hopeing you were going to try it yourself before it was simply answered. Do please try things before asking for help, it's a much better approach to learning than counting on others to help. Eventhough that's what we do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a formula field Profile__c like this:
CASE( ABS(Marks__c/ 10 ) , 1, 'B', 2, 'C',3,'D','A') . Also add some validation rule that  Marks__c should always be greater than 1